# git config --global returns "syntax error near unexpected token `)'" error

Tags: git, command-prompt

When I try:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Me"
```

it returns me this error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1)'
```

I'm running **Git 2.6.3** on **Windows 7** at **C:\opt\git-2.6.3** and my **.gitconfig** was - at first - empty.

But, beside this error, it was filled with:

```
[user]
name = Me
```

and, for each command that I type, the Prompt returns me the same error...

How can I fix this?

With gratitude,

Comment: The problem is not with git, but with your shell. Check your .bash_profile (or any other config file). Also, Stack Overflow is actually only for programming questions. You should ask this sort of questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: Delete your .gitconfig file and try that command again. If you still see an error, it's your shell like Leo said. If this is the case, I might suggest re-installing Git.

Comment: Also, unless you specifically check off an option during the Git install process, the default windows command prompt will probably not have full functionality. Ensure you are using the Git command prompt.

Comment: @LéoLam I don't believe this is off-topic.  [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says "we feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them", but that "software tools commonly used by programmers" is fair game.

Comment: As @LéoLam said, it's probably your .bashrc that's messed up.  If I had to guess, I'd say something with the prompt (perhaps a quote missing, or something similar).

Answer (score 16):

I also traced it to the \n following $(__git_ps1)

Simplifying the PS1 prompt:

This works:

```
PS1='$(__git_ps1)'
```

This does not; it gives the syntax error message:

```
PS1='$(__git_ps1)\n'
```

However, giving the \n in ASCII *does* work:

```
PS1='$(__git_ps1)\012'
```

Interestingly, after the \012 you can use \n again:

```
PS1='$(__git_ps1)\012\n'
```

---

**Note**:  I found additional errors in my PS1; not sure if they were there before, something odd happened when I updated git, or maybe (probably!) from my messing around in the distant past...

My PS1 (after updating git earlier today) was:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w \[\033[1m\]\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\n$ '
```

This gives the syntax error, but also that first escape sequence is wrong:

```
wrong!   PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM ...
right!   PS1='\[\033[0;m$MSYSTEM ...
```

the bracket after \033 was backwards *and* the 'm' was missing...

My corrected PS1 is now:

```
PS1='\[\033[0;m$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\]\w \[\033[1m\]\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\012$ '
```

this gives my prompt as:

```
MINGW64:/c/Users/aweiner       <-white
aweiner@ajw-sony ~             <- green, dir in yellow, git branch name in red
$
```

(and yes, it's way verbose, so I'll probably mess with it some more...)

Comment: adding `\012` after the closing `)` worked like a charm in Git Bash for Windows

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue with git bash interpreter.

I have bisected the definition of PS1 in my .profile, and found that the problem appears if there were `\n` somewhere AFTER `$(blablabla)`.
Even "blablabla" is absolutely innocent, like `echo helloworld`.

My solution was to emit the linefeed using another function:

```
function echonewline() {
  echo -e "\n "
  # last line must be non-empty - I emit a whitespace
}

PS1=\n...all...stuff...$(__git_ps1)...colors...$(echonewline) $
# newlines before first function call are welcome.
```

Looks weird, but it works.

Git bash v. 2.8.2 for Windows.